# Java: OutOfMemory exception when trying to read objects from a very large file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, out-of-memory, fileinputstream

I have saved almost 10k objects in a file using this code below:

```
boolean exists = Tools.getDeviceInfo().exists();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Tools.getDeviceInfo(), true);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = exists ?
                new ObjectOutputStream(fos) {
                    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
                        reset();
                    }
                }:new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(deviceInfos);
```

Now when I'm trying to read the file it is throwing OutOfMemory exception. How I can resolve this. Below is the code for reading objects.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Tools.getDeviceInfo());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        ArrayList<DeviceInfo> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            arrayList.addAll((ArrayList<DeviceInfo>)ois.readObject());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ois.close();
        return arrayList;
```

The reason i want to read all objects is I want to show all the data in tableview so i need to add all the (10k rows) into arraylist and show it on tableview.
Is there any option to limit the readObject(), so it can only retrieve few objects from a very large file.
How I can improve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're serializing and deserializing the entire collection in one go. If you write the individual objects (rather than the containing `ArrayList`) you'd be able to read a range at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You are kind of stuffed here.

It looks like you have put all of the objects into a list and then saved the list to the file using a single `writeObject` call.

If you do that, you don't have any real choice but to read back the entire list.  I guess, conceivably, you could implement a hack (with custom read object methods or similar) to "read" the unwanted `DeviceInfo` objects as `null` to save space.  But that is liable to have down-sides.

One solution is to serialize the original list by serializing the elements individually.  Then you can read them back one at a time, and ignore the ones that you don't want.   It is not efficient, but you should be able to avoid filling the heap with objects that are not currently needed.

A better solution would be to use another method of saving the data:

- You could use an RDBMS, a NoSQL database or a flat-file database (like BerkleyDB) and select just the rows that you want to display.
- You could use another serialization format such as JSON, XML or CSV which has a streaming API.  Then you stream the entire file and only reify the elements you want to display.

A database of some kind would be preferable.

Comment: Hmm. Make sense, Now i'm going to store my data in a local database (h2 database). Can i read the data from H2 database via streaming api? coz i want to read all the rows and show it on table

Comment: Sure.  H2 supports JDBC and JDBC resultsets stream the rows.  But you can do better than that.  You can select just the rows that you want to display.

Answer (score -1):

In order to read 10k objects from a file please try to use java.util.scanner

```
FileInputStream fInputStream = null;
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        fInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);//file path
        scanner = new Scanner(fInputStream, "UTF-8");
         ArrayList<DeviceInfo> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        DeviceInfo dObj = new DeviceInfo();
        dObj = scanner.nextLine();
        arrayList.addall(dObj);
        }
        // note that Scanner suppresses out of memory exception
        if (scanner.ioException() != null) {
            throw scanner.ioException();
        }
    } finally {
        if (fInputStream != null) {
            fInputStream.close();
        }
        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }
        }
```

The above code will help to process lines(one object each line) in a large file without iteratively, without exhausting the available memory.

Comment: You cannot use a `Scanner` to read objects written using `ObjectOutputStream`.  It is a binary format.  And if you are proposing an alternative representation, there are better approaches than "writing it out as lines of text" ... and then writing a hand-built parser to parse the lines.

Comment: I tried this approach but this doesn't work as i have used ObjectOutputStream and saved a Collection of objects.